# GET_DDL function in snowflake doesn't work properly for streams

Tags: sql, stream, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ddl

I faced out with following issue during using [GET_DLL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl) function in Snowflake:

I expect to see a fully-qualified names (schema_name + object_name at least) for tables which I use in stream definitions. But in resultset I see table names only. It works properly for cases when stream and table are in the same schema, but I get incorrect result for cases when table and stream are in the different schemas.

Script for re-produce:

```
create or replace schema schema_1;

use schema schema_1;
create or replace table table_1
(
    id int
);


create or replace schema schema_2;

use schema schema_2;
create or replace stream stream_2 on table schema_1.table_1;
  
select get_ddl('stream', 'stream_2', true);
```

Result: `create or replace stream DB_NAME.SCHEMA_2.STREAM_2 on table TABLE_1;`

I expect to see following: `create or replace stream DB_NAME.SCHEMA_2.STREAM_2 on table SCHEMA_1.TABLE_1;`

Tested for `select get_ddl('stream', 'stream_2')` as well, but result is the same.

Maybe someone could provide any ideas how can I get ddl of the stream with correct paths?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me - so it's probably worth reporting to Snowflake Support. If you, for example, create a view in one schema against a table in another schema then get_ddl returns a FQN for the table - so the behaviour is not consistent. I don't believe there is a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

This is by design and it is documented on Snowflake docs [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl)

```
Optional:

<use_fully_qualified_names_for_recreated_objects>

If TRUE, the generated DDL statements use fully-qualified names for the objects to be recreated.


Default: FALSE.

Note

This does not affect the names of other objects referenced in the DDL statement (e.g. the name of a table referenced in a view definition).
```

Observe that under the note we document that other objects referenced are not affected.

If you would like to have a behavior where also other objects referenced are using FQN you can open an [Idea](https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas) for it.

Comment: this may be the case but the behaviour is still not consistent and therefore I would argue it is a bug. Snowflake should either show the FQN for other objects or just the name - it shouldn't have different behaviour depending on the object whose DDL the function is returning

Comment: The FQN is shown only for the object for which the DDL is applied, not any references inside and this is consistent. Behavior is not different depending on the object whose DDL the function is returning (DDL returns one main object, the rest are references). Yes, it would be nice to show it for the referenced objects but it's currently not implemented and documented, therefore I see it like a feature request.

Comment: If a view references a table then Get_ddl shows the FQN for the table , as well as for the view name (if the last param is set to true)